# Controller url register, but not methods, spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@Controller(value = "/rest")     
public class AppRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value= "/upload-metadata",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Boolean uploadMetadata(@RequestBody MetadataForm metadataForm){
        Logger.info("uploading metadata : {0}", metadataForm.getTitle());
        return true;
    };
```

and my log message shows only :

```
Jul 11, 2014 1:54:09 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/rest] onto handler '/rest'
Jul 11, 2014 1:54:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 864 ms
```

the actual requestmappings for methods are not shown ? And I get 404 for them :

```
Jul 11, 2014 1:54:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/rest/upload-metadata] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

Comment: move value = "/rest" to a RequestMapping on class basis

Comment: @HankLapidez huh ? the way I have shown shoul dbe fine, shouldn't it ? Works in 3.2. this is 4 btw.

Comment: I have never used Controller(value). Always the other approach and had no problems. the source says that value is for the component name. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.0.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.java#Controller

Comment: The value on the `@Controller` annotation is the bean name, not a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. The Method should get called on myapp/rest/upload-metadata

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest")     
public class AppRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value= "/upload-metadata",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Boolean uploadMetadata(@RequestBody MetadataForm metadataForm){
        Logger.info("uploading metadata : {0}", metadataForm.getTitle());
        return true;
    };
```

Comment: but the log messaghe shows that rest has been registered ?

Answer (score 0):

Though you did not give the complete controller; Refer to the spring documentation for @RequestMapping and @Controller your mapping should be this.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest")     
public class AppRestController {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppRestController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "/upload-metadata",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody 
public Boolean uploadMetadata(@RequestBody MetadataForm metadataForm) {
    log.info("uploading metadata : {0}", metadataForm.getTitle());
    return true;
}
```

}

All the best